# Window theme doesn't match decoration

Tags: 16.04, themes, mate

I'm using the MATE Desktop on a Ubuntu installation, and I've come across this strange inconsistency. So far I've only noticed it in Clementine and Antimicro, but I have no idea how to fix it. Other programs like Thunderbird, Firefox, and Nautilus all work properly, but these programs have a different theme and I can't properly explain it.

[image: Antimicro, showing a different theme than what is set.]

[image: Clementine, exhibiting the exact same issue.]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found my own answer after scouring Google search results. These programs use Qt for their user interface. I installed the package `qt4-qtconfig` and ran it with `qtconfig`, choosing the GTK+ GUI style and configuring window and background colours to match the theme. Clementine and Antimicro now match well with my theme, as well as all other programs that use Qt for theming.

[image]